# Multiple field separator in awk (Field separator being together )

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have a text file

```
abc-AB9-3.2-def  
abc-5.6-def
```

I need to get the string that is before "-" symbol followed by "any number".
ie. I need to get string before -3 in first case and -5 in second case.

Output expected is:

```
abc-AB9
abc
```

Please help. My delimiter is "-" followed by any number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk -F"-[0-9]+" '{print $1}'  yourfile
```

(OR)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="-[0-9]+" } {print $1}' yourfile
```

Another way ( as **Jotne** commented ):

```
awk -F"-[0-9]" '{$0=$1}1' yourfile
```

Comment: I think it's an GNU awk solution.

Comment: @AvinashRaj This is a general `awk` solution.  If this had been `RS`, yes then you need `GNU awk`

Comment: @sat you do not need the `+` sign, since OP says any number so `"-[0-9]"` is enough.  And you could shorten it some to: `awk -F"-[0-9]" '{$0=$1}1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` to delete the irrelevant parts:

```
sed 's/-[0-9].*//' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\(.*\)-[0-9].*/\1/g' file
abc-AB9
abc
```

Through grep,

```
$ grep -oP '.*(?=-\d)' file
abc-AB9
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(.*?)-\d.*/)' your_file
```

Test:

```
> cat temp
abc-AB9-3.2-def  
abc-5.6-def
> perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(.*?)-\d.*/)' temp
abc-AB9
abc
>
```